# PIG extract min from multiple numbers

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig data file

```
a|1,5,8,4
b|2,6,7,3
c|12,9,6,13
```

I need to generate

```
a,1
b,2
c,6
```

I'm trying

```
Result =  foreach Data generate 
          (chararray) id  as id,(long) MIN(STRSPLIT(values, ',')) as min_value;
```

This throws `Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.MIN as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.` as numbers are stored as string `1,5,8,4` in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Winnie's answer, but its robust, i.e. it can handle variable size of second column. You can use TransposeTupleToBag UDF from DataFu lib (http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/util/TransposeTupleToBag.html)

```
result1 = FOREACH data GENERATE (chararray) id  as id, STRSPLIT(values, ',') as numbers;
result2 = FOREACH result1 GENERATE id, TransposeTupleToBag(numbers) as numbers;
result3 = FOREACH result2 GENERATE id, MIN(numbers) as min;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but here are the steps you need to follow. These could all be done in consecutive `FOREACH`s, or even nested to save space -- there's no reduce phase here.

1. Split the string into a tuple of values, as you've done: `STRSPLIT(values, ',') AS tup`
2. Put the elements of the tuple into a bag: `TOBAG(tup.$0, tup.$1, tup.$2, tup.$3) AS bag`
3. Compute the min as usual: `MIN(bag) AS min`

Note that this requires that the number of values in each string is constant. If this is not the case, you'll need to write a UDF that produces the bag (or even the minimum itself, depending on how general you want to make it).